# Moment in typescript not recognized?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, momentjs, angular-moment

I ran these commands:

```
npm install tsd -g
tsd install moment --save
```

it is also injecting into my module but when i am accessing it it is not recognizing moment.

eg.

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
```

Could you please help me out.

Comment: *> it is not recognizing moment* 
What do you mean? Please add more info. What errors appear, etc?

Comment: error is could not find 'moment' module in my typescript page

Answer (score 0):

Try this .

```
npm install @types/moment --save-dev
```

It is best to install the typescript definition files as developer dependencies

Then import like this

```
import * as moment from "moment"
```